# SDL2 Clion executable unable to start correctly 0xc000007b

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, sdl, clion

I'm trying to run the executable of my application made with CLion and I get the error `0xc000007b` ([`STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55)).

If I launch the program from CLion the application start normally without any error, the problem occurs only if I try to launch the EXE.

I use SDL2, SDL2_image and SDL2_ttf.  I always had this problem with SDL.

Project structure:

```
./cmake-build-debug
   /SDL2.dll, SDL2_image.dll, SDL2_ttf.dll
   /myProgram.exe
./include
   /SDL2/
      /*.a
./lib
   /SDL2/
      /*.h
./src
   /main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

  SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
          "GameEngine",
          SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
          SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
          640,
          480,
          0
  );

  SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
  SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

  bool should_quit = false;
  while (!should_quit) {

      SDL_Event event;
      while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
          switch (event.type) {
              case SDL_QUIT:
                  should_quit = true;
                  break;
          }
          break;
      }

  }

  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;
}
```

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(GameEngine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/SDL2)
set(SDL2_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/SDL2)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${SDL2_LIB_DIR})


file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp
    )

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mingw32 SDL2main SDL2 SDL2_image SDL2_ttf)
```

Comment: It means you have a 32-bit application that attempts to load a 64-bit dll or vise versa.

Comment: I have been carefull to only use x86_64 version of sdl lib, include and dll, i686 just don't works.

Comment: You may open your executable in [Dependency Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker) or the more modern tool [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to find out what DLLs are loaded at runtime or are missing.

Comment: Thanks you !  I had already tried dependency walker but i don't manage to make it works. Dependencies show me that i was missing llibstdc++-6.dll and libwinpthread-1.dll.